# Unable to remove domain name from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, users, domain-server

I have a domain called "csez.testcorp.com". I have created a user called "admin". 
But in terminal it appears as "testcorp\admin@admin:~$"

I want to remove the testcorp in front of the domain user name
Is it possible to remove?

Answer (score 0):

If what you are wanting to do is just change the look of terminal, you need to change you $PS1 variable. [This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) is a good website to see. Basically you edit your .bashrc and at the end, put `export PS1=THIS IS MY TERMINAL:`. Obviously change THIS IS MY TERMINAL: to something you like (look at the page linked above). You terminal would look like this:

```
THIS IS MY TERMINAL:echo yes
yes
THIS IS MY TERMINAL:echo no
no
THIS IS MY TERMINAL:
```

If you are wanting to actually change your hostname, modify /etc/hosts and /etc/hostnames to your liking using a sudoed text editor.